# VB .Net - ShouldSerialize function

Tags: vb.net, properties, reset

I have a problem with ShouldSerialize function.
I defined an usercontrol with a label (named Label1) on it.
Now i put the code below in the usercontrol class :

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class UserControl1

Dim _Range As UShort = 100

Private Sub UserControl1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label1.Text = _Range
End Sub

Public Function ShouldSerializeTBValueRange() As Boolean
    Return _Range <> 200
End Function

Public Sub ResetTBValueRange()
    _Range = 200
    Label1.Text = _Range
End Sub

Public Property TBValueRange As UShort
    Get
        Return _Range
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Steps As UShort)
        _Range = Steps
        Label1.Text = _Range
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

Now in a new form include the usercontrol.
In the properties grid of the usercontrol u can find the property TBValueRange.
If you right click in the property name you can Reinit the property.
After reinit u can see value 200 in the property.
Now, regenerate the project will reset the property to the initial value (id 100).
Why the value 200 didn't stay?
If i replace the line `Return _Range <> 200` in the function ShouldSerializeTBValueRange() by

> Return Not _Range.Equals(200)

it will work.
i don't understand.

Anyone could explain this?

Comment: "Now, regenerate the project will reset the property to the initial value (id 100). Why the value 200 didn't stay?" Because this line `Dim _Range As UShort = 100` will be called every time you create a new instance, i.e. run the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i found something, with the use of PropertyDescriptor.
For whose are interested, we can save properties in the designer.vb file and test the value to reset.
here is my program, based on the article from [MSDN - Microsft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Windows.Forms.Design

<Designer(GetType(DemoControlDesigner))>
Public Class UserControl1

Dim _MyProperty1 As String = "Test1"
Dim _MyProperty2 As Integer = 100
Dim _MyProperty3 As UShort = 200

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
End Sub

Public Function CanResetMyProperty1() As Boolean
    Return _MyProperty1 <> "Test"
End Function

Public Sub ResetMyProperty1()
    _MyProperty1 = "Test"
End Sub

Public Property MyProperty1 As String
    Get
        Return _MyProperty1
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        _MyProperty1 = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Function CanResetMyProperty2() As Boolean
    Return _MyProperty2 <> 150
End Function

Public Sub ResetMyProperty2()
    _MyProperty2 = 150
End Sub

Public Property MyProperty2 As Integer
    Get
        Return _MyProperty2
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
        _MyProperty2 = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Function CanResetMyProperty3() As Boolean
    Return _MyProperty3 <> _MyProperty2
End Function

Public Sub ResetMyProperty3()
    _MyProperty3 = _MyProperty2
End Sub

Public Property MyProperty3 As UShort
    Get
        Return _MyProperty3
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As UShort)
        _MyProperty3 = Value
    End Set
End Property

End Class


Friend NotInheritable Class SerializePropertyDescriptor
Inherits PropertyDescriptor
Private _pd As PropertyDescriptor = Nothing

Public Sub New(ByVal pd As PropertyDescriptor)
    MyBase.New(pd)
    _pd = pd
End Sub

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Attributes() As AttributeCollection
    Get
        Return Me._pd.Attributes
    End Get
End Property

Protected Overrides Sub FillAttributes(ByVal attributeList As IList)
    MyBase.FillAttributes(attributeList)
End Sub

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ComponentType() As Type
    Get
        Return Me._pd.ComponentType
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Converter() As TypeConverter
    Get
        Return Me._pd.Converter
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides Function GetEditor(ByVal editorBaseType As Type) As Object
    Return Me._pd.GetEditor(editorBaseType)
End Function

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property IsReadOnly() As Boolean
    Get
        Return Me._pd.IsReadOnly
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property PropertyType() As Type
    Get
        Return Me._pd.PropertyType
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides Function CanResetValue(ByVal component As Object) As Boolean
    Try
        Return CallByName(component, "CanReset" & _pd.Name, CallType.Get, Nothing)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return False
End Function

Public Overrides Function GetValue(ByVal component As Object) As Object
    Return Me._pd.GetValue(component)
End Function

Public Overrides Sub ResetValue(ByVal component As Object)
    Me._pd.ResetValue(component)
End Sub

Public Overrides Sub SetValue(ByVal component As Object, ByVal val As Object)
    Me._pd.SetValue(component, val)
End Sub

Public Overrides Function ShouldSerializeValue(ByVal component As Object) As Boolean
    Return True
End Function

End Class

Class DemoControlDesigner
Inherits ControlDesigner
Dim PropertiesToSerialize As String() = {"MyProperty1", "MyProperty2", "MyProperty3"}

Protected Overrides Sub PostFilterProperties(ByVal properties As IDictionary)
    Dim original As PropertyDescriptor
    For Each PropName As String In PropertiesToSerialize
        If properties.Contains(PropName) Then
            original = properties(PropName)
            properties(PropName) = New SerializePropertyDescriptor(original)
        End If
    Next
    MyBase.PostFilterProperties(properties)
End Sub
End Class
```

For each property that should be serialized and tested for reset, we should write a sub "CanResetPropertyName" which test the value to reset (see sample).
And the values stay now, even if we regenerate the project.
It's working fine for me, maybe it can be improved.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The methods are working as coded.  The thing which *seems* to not work as expected is the `Not _Range.Equals(200)` portion.

- You initialize `_Range` to 100: `Dim _Range As UShort = 100`
- Then, your `ShouldSerializeTBValueRange` method tells VS to *only* save the range value when it is *not* `200`:  `Return _Range <> 200`
- So, when you reset it to `200` in the IDE, it wont save a value of `200`, and the initial value of `100` displays.

The code uses one value for the default, `100` but use a different value for `ShouldSerialize` test.  You should either change it to use a default of 200:

```
Dim _Range As UShort = 200
```

**Or** change the `ShouldSerialize` test to use `100`:

```
Public Function ShouldSerializeTBValueRange() As Boolean
    Return _Range <> 100
End Function
```

---

Treating the default value as the default, and using only *one* value for the default everything works as expected using just `ShouldSerializexxx` and `Resetxxx` with no need for anything else.

```
' THIS is the default value -
'     ie the value that need not be saved because the
'     control automatically starts with that value
Dim _Range As UShort = 200US

' Controls:
'   - displays the prop value in Bold in the property window 
'           when the value is NOT the default
'   - saves the value when it is NOT the default
'   - enables/disables the RESET function
Public Function ShouldSerializeTBValueRange() As Boolean
    Return (_Range <> 200US)
End Function
```

[image]

Using one value for the actual default (100) and then returning T/F based on a **different** value (200) results in

- 100 being saved when it need not be
- 200 *not* being saved when it should be
- the `Reset` menu item and **Bold value** being in the incorrect state

---

The oddity is that `Not _Range.Equals(200)` seems to fail.  It returns `False` after a reset (to 200) which causes the value to be saved when it really should not.  There are 2 overloads for this:

```
 UInt16.Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
 UInt16.Equals(v As UShort) As Boolean
```

If you pass anything other than an actual `UInt16/UShort`, the value will be boxed as `Object`.  So, `Not _Range.Equals(200)` is using the first because `200` is `Int32`.  The ILCode for that version is:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return obj is ushort && this == (ushort)obj;
}
```

The test will fail the first test because `obj` contains an `Int32`.  If you pass a `UShort`, it will work:

```
UShort.Equals(_Range, 200US)
'or:
_Range.Equals(200US)
```

All good reasons to understand the different data types, avoid boxing (`As Object`) and always and forever set `Option Strict On`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all to have spent time on my question.
I found my answer : when ShouldSerialize function return false the property value isn't save in the file Form1.designer.vb, so it gets the original value.
For my needed the ShouldSerialize function should always return true.

```
Public Function ShouldSerializeTBValueRange() As Boolean
    Return true
End Function
```

So the property value will always be saved.
Now, what i'm looking for is how to control the context menu of the property grid.
I want the option "Reinit" greyed when the value is good.

Comment: `I want the option "Reinit" greyed when the value is good` cant happen if you are telling VS that the value has changed no matter what it is.